# In a sequence of variable sized objects, given an index find the size of the object

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, indexing

I'm working with an object where the size of each data-blocks within that object grows as the object grows in size. So, it'll have 16 blocks of size 1MB then 8 blocks of size 2MB and 4 of 4MB.)

Given an index (to a data-block in our design) I should be able to quickly return size of this block (1MB/2MB/4MB).

This is what I have right now:

```
private blockType getBlockType(final int blockIndex) {
    if (blockIndex < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Received illegal blockIndex for the file");

    } else if (blockIndex < NUM_SMALLBLOCKS) {
        return blockType.SMALL;

    } else if (blockIndex >= NUM_SMALLBLOCKS && blockIndex < (NUM_SMALLBLOCKS + NUM_STDBLOCKS)) {
        return blockType.STANDARD;

    } else if (blockIndex >= (NUM_SMALLBLOCKS + NUM_STDBLOCKS) && blockIndex < MAX_NUM_BLOCKS) {
        return blockType.LARGE;

    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Received illegal blockIndex");
    }
}
```

The calculations look lengthy and difficult to read and understand. Please suggest better way to achieve this.

P.S: Apologies for the convoluted question statement earlier, working late at night.

Comment: What does the index value 30 mean, and why does it indicate that you have to use object of size 4?

Comment: Can you explain what is the aim here? It appears to be a dynamic programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array `a` of size the sum of all the sizes. Set every index in your array so that it points to the object you want. Doing so, `a[index]` would simply return the proper object.

It is both easy and efficient.

Comment: I did that, I was told to avoid keeping additional data structures which. I re-wrote my implementation to be more recursive and got rid of such DS..I just want to clean up what I have now..any smart language solutions?

Answer (score 0):

So you'll never have to support more than around 8 elements? You can just store them all in a normal array, one after another, and then count your way through it for every query.

Comment: Let's just assume I'm told not to do that.

Comment: If you want the smartest solution it will depend 100% on your context, which includes the number of elements you have.

Comment: well, # of elements for now are 64 but they are expected to grow in future and we have no clue how much can they grow.